# How do you add parens to a CheckConstraint in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

The following constraint:

```
        models.CheckConstraint(name='approved_by_someone',
                               check=(models.Q(approved_at__isnull=True)
                                      | (models.Q(approved_by__isnull=False)
                                         & models.Q(approved_at__isnull=False))))
```

Generates a postgres constraint that looks like this:

```
Check constraints:
"approved_by_someone" CHECK (approved_at IS NULL OR approved_by_id IS NOT NULL AND approved_at IS NOT NULL)
```

The parens in my python code disappear when converted into a sql constraint.  My first thoughts were, OK, I can put those back by adding a models.Q around the AND condition:

```
        models.CheckConstraint(name='approved_by_someone',
                               check=(models.Q(approved_at__isnull=True)
                                      | models.Q(models.Q(approved_by__isnull=False)
                                                 & models.Q(approved_at__isnull=False))))
```

But still, NO the constraint is unchanged.

Comment: No, the brackets are only part of the Python file, so these are even no longer available after parsing so to speak. The ORM apparently does not think these are necessary here. The `AND` has precedence over the `OR` so the way it iks written is correct: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-syntax.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE although I agree making it more explicit might be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@willem-van-onsem was correct, the order of precedence makes the above correct without needing the parens.  He is also correct that having the parens would be good for the human's state of mind :-)

So I'm guessing you would need `models.Q` around the expression, AND the expression would need to require the parens to actually get them in the SQL.